# Set dropdown menu as main menu item

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a problems with adding a dropdown as a menu item.

This is my main menu:

```
Ext.define('ECR.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',

        'ECR.view.main.MainController',
        'ECR.view.main.MainModel',
        'ECR.view.main.List'
    ],

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',

    ui: 'navigation',
    tabBar: {
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        },
        border: false
    },

    defaults: {
        iconAlign: 'top',
        bodyPadding: 15
    },

    items: [{
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'fa-home',
            bind: {
                html: 'Test'
            }

        },
        {   title: 'DROPDOWN',
            iconCls: 'fa-cogs',
            bind: {
                html: 'Test'
            },
            xtype: 'dropdownButton'
        },

        {
            title: 'Administration',
            iconCls: 'fa-cogs',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Reporting',
            iconCls: 'fa-calendar',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Help',
            iconCls: 'fa-question',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Account',
            iconCls: 'fa-user',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

And here I am trying to add the dropdown where I previously defined:

```
{   title: 'DROPDOWN',
            iconCls: 'fa-cogs',
            bind: {
                html: 'Test'
            },
            xtype: 'dropdownButton'
        },
```

This is the definition of dropdown:

```
Ext.define('My.harun.Button', {
    extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',
    alias: ['widget.dropdownButton'],

    text: 'Menu button',

    arrowAlign: 'bottom',
    menu: [
        { text: 'Item 1' },
        { text: 'Item 2' },
        { text: 'Item 3' },
        { text: 'Item 4' }
    ],
    listeners: {
        mouseover: function() {
            this.showMenu();
        }
    }
});
```

But this does not work. However I tried to create it manually using `Ext.create()` :

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Menu button',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    arrowAlign: 'bottom',
    menu: [
        { text: 'Item 1' },
        { text: 'Item 2' },
        { text: 'Item 3' },
        { text: 'Item 4' }
    ],
    listeners: {
        mouseover: function() {
            this.showMenu();
        }
    }
})
```

So far I am getting only this:

[image]

I managed to put the item in main menu but it is still not a dropdown one. And when I click on that item it shows really big button in the main screen (here where "Test" is written).

Is there a way to fix this or I must use Toolbar?

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2le7) if this help.

Comment: Actually, I want this "Menu item" to be instead of "DROPDOWN".

Comment: Can you please bit more explain why you want on `DROPDOWN` (tab item)?

Comment: Because it is a common thing to have a dropdown item in a menu. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with `tabConfig`. If anyone needs dropdown item in your menu, include this in your `items` list:

```
{
    tabConfig:
    {
        title: 'Dropdown menu',
        iconCls: 'fa-home',
        menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',
        {
            width: 100,
            plain: true,
            items: [
            {
                text: 'Dropdown Item 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Dropdown Item 2'
            },
            {
                text: 'Dropdown Item 3'
            }]
        })
    }
},
```